So sorry, its kinda NSFW, but can you help me?
Once again, so sorry if its kinda NSFW or awkward. But i can’t seem to understand this problem. I’m also just a beginner. So please, if you have time, can you kindly guide and help me?
I recently created sims 4 adult clothing. I want to edit this outfit

And i already managed to make it like this

But from here, when i upload to Sims file studio, it looks like this

Can you guys help me figure it out, how to make the texture looks like the second picture. Is it hard to do it?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hello, have you deleted the faces?

Hi there. You wrote "And i already managed to make it like this "... it would help to know what you exactly did to achieve this.

@moonboots no, i have’nt. I use sculpting mode

@Blunder Thanks for answering. I used sculpting mode and use a grab mode to make the mesh looks like that.
